# SQL Server Query Where Not Exists

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm have a tough time getting the intended results. I have a table that consist of server name and all disk drive letters associated with that server. I want to query the rows and return a distinct list of server names where a specific drive letter does not exist on that server. So, in this case, I want to know all servers that do not have a "D" drive.

I've tried using a temp table, not exists, left joins between temp tables, not in (select...) from temp table and I'm unable to retrieve a distinct list of servers.

Can someone help me with a query that can to this?

I've included an example table:

```
CREATE TABLE DRIVES  (
SERVERNAME NVARCHAR(50),
DRIVE NVARCHAR(5)
)

INSERT INTO DRIVES(SERVERNAME, DRIVE)

SELECT '0001', 'C'
UNION
SELECT '0001', 'D'
UNION
SELECT '0001', 'E'
UNION
SELECT '0001', 'F'
UNION
SELECT '0002', 'C'
UNION
SELECT '0002', 'D'
UNION
SELECT '0002', 'E'
UNION
SELECT '0002', 'F'
UNION
SELECT '0003', 'C'
UNION
SELECT '0003', 'E'
UNION
SELECT '0003', 'F'
UNION
SELECT '0004', 'C'
UNION
SELECT '0004', 'D'
UNION
SELECT '0004', 'E'
UNION
SELECT '0004', 'F'
UNION
SELECT '0005', 'C'
UNION
SELECT '0005', 'E'
UNION
SELECT '0005', 'F'
```

The results should return servers 0003 and 0005 only as not have a "D" drive

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Because left joins and not exists should work if you've tried them (you don't need a temporary table for it). I'm also fairly sure this question has been asked hundreds of times before so it shouldn't have been too hard to find an answer if you searched for it.

Comment: Thanks Guys! And sorry for the slow response. I was out of the loop for a couple days. Anyway, I tried both left join and not exists (as well as other options such as not like, not in, etc.) and I could not get a distinct list as well as the results contained servers that did have a D drive. What I would get was all the other drives except the D drive (i.e., C, E, F, G, H, etc) but that wasn't what I needed. This should have been very simple but wasn't sure what I was missing.

Comment: I ended up getting what I needed by concatenating the rows into a single list of drive letters per server and then querying against the drive column (where drive not like '%D%'). For example - [server 1] [C, D, E, F] I know that might seem like overkill but I'm still puzzled why I couldn't get it to work just using not exists or a join.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did to get the results I was looking for:

```
CREATE TABLE DRIVES (
    SERVERNAME NVARCHAR(50),
    DRIVE NVARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO DRIVES(SERVERNAME,DRIVE)

SELECT DISTINCT
    tt.SystemName00,
    STUFF (( SELECT DISTINCT ',  ' + SUB.[deviceid00] AS [text()] 
                FROM [SMS].dbo.Logical_Disk_DATA SUB
                WHERE SUB.[SystemName00] = tt.[SystemName00]
                FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '')
FROM [SMS].dbo.Logical_Disk_DATA tt
ORDER BY tt.SystemName00

select *
from DRIVES
where DRIVE not like '%D:%'
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach uses conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SERVERNAME
FROM DRIVES
GROUP BY SERVERNAME
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN DRIVE = 'D' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this .** This will give you data if one of the drive is not there.

```
SELECT SERVERNAME 
FROM DRIVES
WHERE DRIVE IN ( 'C','D','E','F' )
GROUP BY SERVERNAME
HAVING (  COUNT( DISTINCT DRIVE) ) < 4
```

**OUTPUT**

```
SERVERNAME
--------------------------------------------------
0003
0005

(2 rows affected)
```

Comment: Thanks Pawan - Unfortunately this would not work only because the drive letter count is unknown. There could be 2 drives C, D or there could be 10 drive C, E - K.

Comment: ohh ok..so how you are planning to solve this problem ? Are you working any other approach.

Comment: Yes, see right below. I've solved it by concatenating the drives. I posted my solution below. Thanks for following up as well as providing a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like that:

```
select distinct SERVERNAME
from DRIVES
where SERVERNAME not in (select SERVERNAME from DRIVES where DRIVE = 'D')
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d1573/3